# unnexpected jquery .last() behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to build a custom keywords field for my site,

The thing is I have a input div holder where I append inputs by clicking a button, but i check

```
$('div inputs').last().val().length < 3
```

if its smaller than 3 i shake the input, else:

```
$('div inputs').last().after('<input type="text" />')
```

---

**Problem is** that:

`$('div inputs').last().val()`

returns allways the **first** input value, what am i doing wrong?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CLy6B/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have cached your inputs on top, so you are always using the same set of input controls - one.

Define your inputs variable within callback and it will work:

```
$('body').on('click','#addkey',function(e){
    var inputs = $('#keysInput input');

    if(inputs.last().val().length < 3){
        $('#keysInput input').last().effect("shake", { times:1, distance: -5 }, 300);
    }else{
        console.log(inputs.last().val());
        $('#keysInput input').last().after('<input type="text" placeholder="type another keyword" />');            
    }
})
```

Comment: Actually i think it's easier simply updating the cache: inputs = $('#keysInput input');

Comment: If you use it in other places then yes. If not, I would stick with the callback function scope.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/pVJXM/5/

Behaviour: every time you enter`3` character and more and hit `+` click you will get an append an inout at the end.

I used `var inputs = $('#keysInput input:last');` instead of using `.last()` multiple time :) that will do the trick for you.

Hope it helps,

**code**

```
var cont = $('#keysInput');

var addBtn = $('#addKey');

$('body').on('keydown','#keysInput',function(e){

});

$('body').on('click','#addkey',function(e){

    var inputs = $('#keysInput input:last');

    if(inputs.val().length < 3){
        inputs.effect("shake", { times:1, distance: -5 }, 300);
    }else{
        console.log(inputs.last().val());
        inputs.after('<input type="text" placeholder="type another keyword" />');            
    }
})




​
```

Comment: it works because you moved the caching inside the function, you could still use .last() there ;)

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet yep you could :)) was thinking of making if minimilistic approach to the :last call :) cheers

Comment: i see it's a good point, but i guess it looked like you where saying the .last() wasn't working..

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet :) lol yep only for minimilistic approach not meant anything around .last not working, thanks for the comment though, cheers! B-)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your script you select `inputs`:

```
var inputs = $('#keysInput input');
```

After that you use that specific value set when the script is first run, which does not contain newly created fields. In other words: **you work on `inputs` containing only one field (initial one)**.

The solution is to simply re-assign value (list of selected inputs) to this variable.